# How to RequestFocus of last item in ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to request the focus of the last item (`EditText`) of my `ArrayList<String>`

How do I do that?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
int listLength = list.size();
listEditText.requestFocus(listLength);
```

Comment: this will cause ArrayOutOfBoundsException do list.size() - 1;

Answer (score 2):

Indices are 0-based, so you should write `listEditText.requestFocus(list.size() - 1);`.

`list.Size()` is the smallest index (greater than 0) that is off the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, everyone seems to be missing that you have a *list* of `EditText` views. `requestFocus(int)` expects a direction, not an index. The documentation for this:

> Call this to try to give focus to a specific view or to one of its
>   descendants and give it a hint about what direction focus is heading.
>   A view will not actually take focus if it is not focusable
>   (isFocusable() returns false), or if it is focusable and it is not
>   focusable in touch mode (isFocusableInTouchMode()) while the device is
>   in touch mode. See also focusSearch(int), which is what you call to
>   say that you have focus, and you want your parent to look for the next
>   one. This is equivalent to calling requestFocus(int, Rect) with null
>   set for the previously focused rectangle.
>
> Parameters direction  One of FOCUS_UP, FOCUS_DOWN, FOCUS_LEFT, and
>   FOCUS_RIGHT Returns Whether this view or one of its descendants
>   actually took focus.

You need to resolve the last EditText in your list:

```
listOfEditTexts.get(listOfEditTexts.length() - 1).requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! My issue was I wasn't calling it in the right place. I needed to be calling my requestFocus() in my adapter when it creates a new item, not my main. (Something you would not have know) Thanks again tho!